# Unable to autoload constant AuthenticateFromToken, expected ./app/api/authenticate_from_token.rb to define it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload

When I started to writing my first rails API I put all the API code under `app/core/api` directory and added it to the autoload paths

```
config.autoload_paths += %W[
  #{config.root}/lib
  #{config.root}/app/core]
```

Afterwards I decided to move the API classes to the app folder. Now when I am running my tests I am getting this error

```
 Failure/Error: authenticate = API::AuthenticateFromToken.(params[:auth_token])

 LoadError:
   Unable to autoload constant AuthenticateFromToken, expected ./app/api/authenticate_from_token.rb to define it
```

Authenticate from token looks like this:

```
module API
  class AuthenticateFromToken

    prepend SimpleCommand

    def initialize(auth_token)
      @auth_token = auth_token
    end

    def call
      # authenticate code
    end
  end
end
```

Before the moving of the `api` directory from `app/core` to `app` I didn't have any problems with autoloading. What is going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class in under the `API` module, it should be saved under an `api` folder.

The issue is that Rails autoloads all folders under `app` folder by default, so you would need to put it in `app/api/api/authenticate_from_token.rb`

more info: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths-and-eager-load-paths

Comment: Thank you much for the response, it worked! But the new `app/api/api` directory structure seems to be worse so I will revert it to `app/core/api`

Comment: yea agreed. Also, you can remove #{config.root}/app/core from your autoload_paths as it is included by default